# If $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ then $f_n^r \to f^r$ in $L^{p/r}$ for $1\leq r \leq p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to do this problem from Le Gall's Measure Theory book.

If $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ then $f_n^r \to f^r$ in $L^{p/r}$ for $1\leq r \leq p$.

I am really stuck on even where to start. Since there is no finite measure I don't see if I can simplify it using Holder's inequality by splitting on $\{ |f-f_n| \geq \varepsilon\}$.

Comment: Do you mean $f_n^r \to f^r$ in $L^{p/r}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming $f_n,f$ are meant to be non-negative here so that $f_n^r$ and $f^r$ are well-defined for non-integer $r$. Suppose we are working on a measure space $(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$.

Consider the function $g: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = x^r$. Then $g'(x)=rx^{r-1}$ so for $0\le a\le b$, by the mean value theorem we have $|g(a)-g(b)|= |a-b||g'(c)|$ for some $c \in [a,b]$. Hence $|a^r-b^r| \le r|a-b| \max(a,b)^{r-1}$. Therefore we have $$\begin{align*} |f_n^r-f^r| &\le r|f_n-f| \max(f_n,f)^{r-1}\end{align*}$$
and so $$\begin{align*} |f_n^r-f^r|^{p/r} &\le r^{p/r} |f_n-f|^{p/r} \max(f_n,f)^{p-p/r}.\end{align*}$$
Now by applying Hölder's inequality with $r$ and $q := \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{r}}$ we have $$\begin{align*} \int_E |f_n-f|^{p/r}\max(f_n,f)^{p-p/r}\mathrm{d}\mu &\le \left(\int_E |f_n-f|^p \mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/r} \left(\int_E \max(f_n,f)^{q(p-p/r)}\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/q}\\
&= \left(\int_E |f_n-f|^p \mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/r} \left(\int_E \max(f_n,f)^{p}\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/q} \\
&= \|f_n-f\|_{L^p}^{p/r} \|\max(f_n,f)\|_{L^p}^{p/q}\\
&\le \|f_n-f\|_{L^p}^{p/r} \|f_n+f\|_{L^p}^{p/q}\\
&\le  \|f_n-f\|_{L^p}^{p/r} (\|f_n\|_{L^p}+\|f\|_{L^p})^{p/q}\\
&\to 0\text{ as } n\to \infty.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: How do you show the $a^r - b^r$ result for $r$ not an integer?

Comment: Thanks for picking this up, I've edited my answer appropriately.